# Random subsets in function of one column in r

Tags: r

I want to extract `n` rows randomly from a data frame in function of one column.
So with this example :

```
# Reproducible example
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,2e+6,2))
df$V1 <- runif(nrow(df),0,1)
df$V2 <- sample(c(1:10),nrow(df), replace=TRUE)
df$V3 <- sample(c("A","B","C"),nrow(df), replace=TRUE)
```

I want to extract, for example, `n=10`rows for each value of `V2`.

```
# Example of what I need with one value of V2
df1 <- df[which(df$V2==1),]
str(df1)
df1[sample(1:nrow(df1),10),]
```

I do not want to do any `for-loop`so I tried this line with `tapply`:

```
df_objective <- tapply(df$V1, df$V2, function(x) df[sample(1:nrow(df),10),"V2"])
```

which is close to what I want but I lost the third column of the data frame.

I tried this to have complete subsets :

```
df_objective <- by(cbind(df$V1,df$V3), df$V2, function(x) df[sample(1:nrow(df),10),"V2"])
```

but it does not help.

How can I keep all the columns in the subsets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for something like `sample_n` from "dplyr":

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(V2) %>% sample_n(10)
# Source: local data frame [100 x 3]
# Groups: V2
# 
#            V1 V2 V3
# 1  0.51099392  1  B
# 2  0.87098866  1  A
# 3  0.13647752  1  B
# 4  0.15348834  1  B
# 5  0.94096127  1  B
# 6  0.05673849  1  A
# 7  0.69960842  1  C
# 8  0.02246671  1  C
# 9  0.88903430  1  B
# 10 0.52128253  1  A
# ..        ... .. ..
```

Alternatively, there's `stratified` from my "splitstackshape" package.

```
library(splitstackshape)
stratified(df, "V2", 10)
```

Comment: That's pretty concise, there, though sampling isn't the first thing that comes to mind when I see the word "stratified"

Comment: @Frank, it's as in "stratified sampling". What do you think of when you see "stratified"?

Comment: Dunno, hardly ever see it. I guess "hierarchical models"

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[sample(.N, 10)] , V2]
```

Or a faster option as suggested by @Frank

```
setDT(df)[df[,sample(.I,10),V2]$V1]
```

Comment: Obligatory alternative: `setDT(df); df[df[,sample(.I,10),V2]$V1]`

Comment: Ok thank you, the second line works, but the V2 seems to be randomly ordered.

Comment: @user3443183 If you write `keyby=V2` in place of `V2` it should be ordered. They currently show up in order of first appearance.

Comment: Ok, it is ordered now.

Answer (score 1):

You want to sample from the rows, so that should be the first arg to `tapply`, not `V1`:

```
myrows <- unlist(tapply(1:nrow(df),df$V2,sample,size=10))
df1[myrows,]
```